# Neo4j: visiting same edge twice during traversal

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
WITH a
MATCH p=(a)-[:rel1]->(:B)-[:rel2]->(:C)-[:rel3]->(d)<-[:rel3]-(:C)<-[:rel2]-(:B)<-[:rel1]-(a)
WITH d, ... do more things
```

It looks like d nodes where rel3 is shared between d and :C are not being returned. IE p does not include paths when the closed loop goes over the same edge (when "connect the dots" looks like a "key" rather than a "circle"). I think this is the basis for graph database - that you cannot traverse same edge twice in same path? Is there a way to start from a and find all the d nodes that related :B and :C have in common, including those that have same rel3 but different rel1 and rel2, ie to not drop those d nodes where rel3 are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueness of patterns matched is documented in the [Cypher manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/uniqueness/).

You can consider splitting into multiple MATCH clauses but it is hard to provide the exact solution without a better example of what the query is trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks - I think I figured it out. I just need to use a comma for the second part of the query. so it's 
     MATCH p=(a)-[:rel1]->(:B)-[:rel2]->(c)<-[:rel2]-(:B)<-[:rel1]-(a), (c)-[:rel3]->(d)
Will try it and report back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm the way to handle it is:

```
p=(a)-[:rel1]->(:B)-[:rel2]->(c)<-[:rel2]-(:B)<-[:rel1]-(a), (c)-[:rel3]->(d)
```